# Flutter Using Controller from a child widget

Tags: flutter, carousel

I'm fairly  new to Flutter and a few days ago I run into carousel_slider package.

One of the examples provided in the [doc](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/carousel_slider#-example-tab-) is a Manually Controlled Slider, but when I change how the widget is build I lose the onPressed ability since the child widget does not know what the _controller is. Which is the proper way to pass info from the state to the child so the child can call _controller.nextPage(), _controller.previousPage() or _controller.animateToPage() ?

```dart
class ManuallyControlledSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ManuallyControlledSliderState();
  }
}

class _ManuallyControlledSliderState extends State<ManuallyControlledSlider> {
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Manually controlled slider')),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CarouselSlider(
            items: imageSliders,
            options: CarouselOptions(enlargeCenterPage: true, aspectRatio: 16/9),
            carouselController: _controller,
          ),
          imageSelector(), //MAIN ISSUE

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The child definition:

```dart
class imageSelector extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => _controller.previousPage(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
                  child: Text('←'),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => _controller.nextPage(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
                  child: Text('→'),
                ),
              ),
              ...Iterable<int>.generate(imgList.length).map(
                (int pageIndex) => Flexible(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => _controller.animateToPage(
                        pageIndex,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        curve: Curves.linear),
                    child: Text("$pageIndex"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the imageSelector widget create a variable to access the controller like:

```
class imageSelector extends StatelessWidget {
final CarouselController _controller;
imageSelector(this._controller);
```

now pass the controller value as a parameter when you are calling imageSelector like:

```
imageSelector(_controller)
```

So your corrected code would be:

For ManuallyControlledSlider:

```
class ManuallyControlledSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ManuallyControlledSliderState();
  }
}

class _ManuallyControlledSliderState extends State<ManuallyControlledSlider> {
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Manually controlled slider')),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CarouselSlider(
            items: imageSliders,
            options: CarouselOptions(enlargeCenterPage: true, aspectRatio: 16/9),
            carouselController: _controller,
          ),
          imageSelector(_controller), //Corrected

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the child:

```
class imageSelector extends StatelessWidget {
final CarouselController _controller;
imageSelector(this._controller);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => _controller.previousPage(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
                  child: Text('←'),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => _controller.nextPage(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
                  child: Text('→'),
                ),
              ),
              ...Iterable<int>.generate(imgList.length).map(
                (int pageIndex) => Flexible(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => _controller.animateToPage(
                        pageIndex,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        curve: Curves.linear),
                    child: Text("$pageIndex"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `_controller` as an optional parameter to `imageSelector`.